# Script copy Last Modified object in Windows10

Tags: windows-10, copy, windows-explorer, last-modified

I wanna the script that Copy the last object that modified (based on "Data modified" in Windows Explorer)

For Example:

D:\Source\A1.txt        Data modified: 12/24/2022
D:\Source\A2.txt        Data modified: 12/23/2022

After use that script, Copy only A1.txt in destination path (like F:\destination)